# Sum multidimensional array

Tags: laravel

I need a suggest.
I get a multidimensonal array named $dettaglioOre in a controller of laravel and I try to dd($dettaglioOre) and this is the result:

```
array array:5  
  0 => array:2 [▼
     "categoria" => 1
     "ore" => "3.00"
]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "categoria" => 2
    "ore" => "2.00"
]
  2 => array:2 [▼
     "categoria" => 3
     "ore" => "6.00"
]
  3 => array:2 [▼
     "categoria" => 1
     "ore" => "6.00"
]
  4 => array:2 [▼
     "categoria" => 2
     "ore" => "4.00"
]
]
```

How I can group by categoria with the sum of the hour?

like so:

categoria 1 = 9 hours

categoria 2 = 6 hours

categoria 3 = 6 hours

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You can group by using `Collections`:

```
    $items = [
        [
            "categoria" => 1,
            "ore" => "3.00"
        ],
        [
            "categoria" => 2,
            "ore" => "2.00"
        ],
        [
            "categoria" => 3,
            "ore" => "6.00"
        ],
        [
            "categoria" => 1,
            "ore" => "6.00"
        ],
        [
            "categoria" => 2,
            "ore" => "4.00"
        ]
    ];
    $result = collect($items)
        ->groupBy("categoria")
        ->map(function ($item) {
            $item = collect($item);
            return [
                "categoria" => $item[0]["categoria"],
                "ore_sum" => $item->sum("ore")
            ];
        });

    dd($result->toArray());
```

Here is the result:

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "categoria" => 1
    "ore_sum" => 9.0
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "categoria" => 2
    "ore_sum" => 6.0
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "categoria" => 3
    "ore_sum" => 6.0
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $data) {
    if(!array_key_exists($data['categoria'], $newArray))
        $newArray[ $data['categoria'] ] = 0;
    $newArray[ $data['categoria'] ] += (double)$data['ore'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [  
  [
     "categoria" => 1,
     "ore" => "3.00"
],
  [
    "categoria" => 2,
    "ore" => "2.00"
],
  [
     "categoria" => 3,
     "ore" => "6.00"
],
  [
     "categoria" => 1,
     "ore" => "6.00"
],
 [
     "categoria" => 2,
     "ore" => "4.00"
]
];

foreach($array as $key => $row){
   $grouped[$row['categoria']] += $row['ore'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($grouped);
```